# Line Detection openCV

Tags: opencv

I am running a code to detect lines in openCV 2.1 in visual studio 2008, here is some part of the code:

```
                  IplImage* src=cvLoadImage("parrot.png");

                  IplImage* dst = cvCreateImage( cvGetSize(src), 8, 1 );
                  IplImage* color_dst = cvCreateImage( cvGetSize(src), 8, 3 );
                  CvMemStorage* storage = cvCreateMemStorage(0);
                  CvSeq* lines = 0;
                  int i;
          int choice=0;
                  cvCanny( src, dst, 10, 100, 3 );
```

the code compiles fine,but when run gives the following error: 
OpenCV Error: Unsupported format or combination of formats () in unknown functi
n, file ........\ocv\opencv\src\cv\cvcanny.cpp, line 66

any hints on how to fix this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default when you load an image it loads it as colour image [`cvLoadImage(const char* filename, int iscolor=CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR)`](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/c/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html). Canny requires single channel image as input and output [`void cvCanny(const CvArr* image, CvArr* edges, double threshold1, double threshold2, int aperture_size=3)`](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/c/imgproc_feature_detection.html). So, I think if you load your image as gray scale or convert it later to gray scale it should work.

Either:

```
IplImage* src=cvLoadImage("parrot.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE );
```

Or:

```
cvtColor(src, src, CV_RGB2GRAY);
```